# How can i point the c pointer to v8::object's value

Tags: v8

i want to use `char *p` point to object[key], but is can't get the value.

test code

```
// hello.cc
#include <v8.h>
#include <node.h>

namespace demo
{

using v8::ArrayBuffer;
using v8::Context;
using v8::FunctionCallbackInfo;
using v8::Isolate;
using v8::Local;
using v8::NewStringType;
using v8::Object;
using v8::String;
using v8::Uint8Array;
using v8::Value;

static void getObjectValue(void *object, const char *key, char **value)
{
    Object *obj = (Object *)object;
    Isolate *isolate = obj->GetIsolate();
    Local<Context> context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();
    Local<Value> lKey = String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, key, NewStringType::kNormal).ToLocalChecked();
    Local<Value> lValue = obj->Get(context, lKey).ToLocalChecked();
    String::Utf8Value u8Str(isolate, lValue);  // local value destory after call, so i can't get the value.
    *value = *u8Str;
}

void Method(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value> &args)
{
    Isolate *isolate = args.GetIsolate();
    Local<Context> context = isolate->GetCurrentContext();

    Local<Object> object = args[0]->ToObject(context).ToLocalChecked();
    const char *key = "key";
    char *p = NULL;
    char **value = &p;

    getObjectValue((void *)*object, key, value);
    printf("value: %s\n", p);
}

void Initialize(Local<Object> exports)
{
    NODE_SET_METHOD(exports, "hello", Method);
}

NODE_MODULE(NODE_GYP_MODULE_NAME, Initialize)

} // namespace demo
```

```js
// hello.js
const obj = require("./build/Release/addon.node");
console.log(obj.hello({"key": "aaa"}));
```

```
## binding.gyp
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "target_name": "addon",
      "sources": [ "hello.cc" ]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can i get the correct value???

thank

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use raw pointers to point to things (objects, strings, ...) on V8's heap. The reason is that the garbage collector could move objects around, which would break your pointers. That's why V8 uses "handles" on its API, which are a GC-safe way to refer to objects on the heap. That means you'd use `v8::Local<v8::String>` to point at a string on V8's heap. If you need the handle to be longer lived than the scope of your current `HandleScope`, you can use a `v8::Persistent<v8::String>`.

Of course you can get at the raw character data within a local function, with `String::Utf8Value` just like you've figured out. At that time you can copy it, or compare it, or run any other (read-only) string operation on it (if you modify it, V8 will get confused in interesting ways). If you want to keep the value in terms of standard C++ data structures, you could e.g. construct a `std::string` from it.